# How to create an array based on a generator?

Tags: python, function, numpy, generator, large-data

Say I have a large array:

```
A = 2*np.ones([100, 100, 100])
```

I want to do some calculations on it, for example:

```
def squared_elements(M):
    yield M**2
```

I choose to use a generator function because my array is very big and I don't need all the results. As a matter of fact, I only need, say, a cube of length 10 at the center of the matrix.

If it was a normal function, I could just write:

```
result = squared_elements(A)[45:55, 45:55, 45:55]
```

However, generators are not subscriptable, so this last expression doesn't work.

How can I get the same `result` using my generator function?

Comment: Generators only reduce memory use when the replace chained lists.  They don't help when working `numpy` arrays.  `A[45:55, 45:55, 45:55]` is a `view` of `A`, that doesn't consume more memory.  Just square that.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

```py
result = next(squared_elements(A))
result[45:55, 45:55, 45:55]
```

## Solution to the updated problem

You can slice the subset before squaring

```py
def squared_elements(A, slice_):
    return A[slice_] ** 2

result = squared_elements(A, [slice(45, 55), slice(45, 55), slice(45, 55)])
```

## Notes

- more on `next()` [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/next).
- more on generator functions [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj1x7qhievpAhVHlnIEHQdSDJsQFjACegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.programiz.com%2Fpython-programming%2Fgenerator&usg=AOvVaw2FmmYKmZF4THwym40zkA6Q).

I hope this helps!

Comment: But when you write your first line:
'''result = next(squared_elements(A))'''
Don't you allocate "a lot" of memory to 'result' ?

Comment: Yes. Are you looking for a way to make `result` itself a generator, and not a `numpy` array? (`yield M**2` doesn't do that.)

Comment: Well, in this case, I want my 'result' to be a (10*10*10) array, rather than a (100*100*100) array from which I then take a subset.

The idea is to make the function as readable and flexible as possible, but only "pay" for the sub_part of the result I actually need.

Comment: Yeah... I suppose that's fair play.

I guess I hoped switching to generators would allow me to avoid changing my code too much now that it has to handle more data =p